Get a list of all git pulls including dates and times
I'm trying to get a list of all git pulls I've made on the production branch of the repo myrepo (fake name).
I've tried git reflog --date=iso and got this output:
(capra_production) (base) Me@My-MacBook-Pro-14 myrepo % git reflog --date=iso
527f984 (HEAD -> production, origin/production) HEAD@{2024-10-16 16:06:08 +0100}: pull --ff --recurse-submodules --progress origin: Fast-forward
1002d90 HEAD@{2023-12-01 08:20:44 -0800}: checkout: moving from main to production
0c1cd61 (origin/main, origin/HEAD, main) HEAD@{2023-12-01 07:50:23 -0800}: checkout: moving from production to main
1002d90 HEAD@{2023-12-01 07:28:56 -0800}: checkout: moving from dev to production
50c78e9 (dev) HEAD@{2023-12-01 07:27:49 -0800}: checkout: moving from main to dev
0c1cd61 (origin/main, origin/HEAD, main) HEAD@{2023-12-01 07:27:49 -0800}: reset: moving to HEAD
0c1cd61 (origin/main, origin/HEAD, main) HEAD@{2022-11-28 17:50:14 -0800}: checkout: moving from test to main
0c1cd61 (origin/main, origin/HEAD, main) HEAD@{2022-11-28 17:48:35 -0800}: checkout: moving from dev to test
8dd078a HEAD@{2022-11-28 17:29:10 -0800}: checkout: moving from main to dev
0c1cd61 (origin/main, origin/HEAD, main) HEAD@{2022-09-26 16:30:49 -0700}: pull --tags origin main: Fast-forward
2be0403 HEAD@{2022-09-12 14:58:34 -0700}: pull --ff --progress origin: Fast-forward
da22f9a HEAD@{2022-08-31 08:49:20 -0700}: pull --ff --progress origin: Fast-forward
41e1868 HEAD@{2022-08-15 17:44:43 -0700}: commit: PJ: adjusted variable names
0ad8664 HEAD@{2022-08-10 17:49:55 -0700}: pull --ff --progress origin: Fast-forward
c13b904 HEAD@{2022-02-08 14:14:50 -0800}: pull --progress origin: Fast-forward
fc34083 HEAD@{2021-09-21 23:12:06 +0200}: clone: from https://github.com/<username>/myrepo.git

This seems to list some pulls but it also seems to suggest there has only been one since since Dec 2023 (on 16 October). However, I've done a pull on the production branch circa every month in 2024 and each time there were changes that were pulled through.
Could I be doing something wrong such that not all the pulls are listed?

If you're going to downvote the question then at least let me know why!!!

What branch do you currently have checked out?

@Schwern - git branchsays production

Still being downvoted - maybe tell me what's wrong with my question???

Who knows - downvoters will downvote they often don't say why. Did you find the suggestion to use git reflog --all make any difference? I'm still thinking if pulls make no actual new merge commits they aren't logged - you said they did but are you sure? Can you confirm a case where a pull created a merge commit but it is not in the reflog? Can you reproduce that?

@Jossy I hear ya, drive by down voters are very frustrating.

@topsail - yep all sorted with Schwern's solution! Have marked as accepted! You deleted your comment or I would have given you an upvote for that to spite the naysayers!

Like git log, git reflog will only show you changes reachable from the current commit by default.
If you want to see the reflog for the whole repository, use git reflog --all.

As @chepner points out, the reflog does expire. There's a number of ways this can happen...

Normal garbage collection controlled by...

gc.reflogExpire, default 90 days.
gc.reflogExpireUnreachable, for reflog entries which are no longer reachable, default 30 days.


Manually running git reflog expire.


Keep in mind, though, that the reflog may be pruned over time to remove old entries, regardless of its size.

@chepner Good point, I'll add that.
